# Boundary of $A=[0,1]\cup \Bbb Q$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I'm not sure if this is corect:

$A=\Bbb Q \cup [0,1] $.

$\operatorname{bd}(A) = \operatorname{cl}(A) \cap \operatorname{cl}(A^c)$

$\operatorname{cl}(A)=\Bbb R$

$\operatorname{cl}(A^c) = \Bbb R \setminus [0,1] \implies \operatorname{bd}(A) = \Bbb R \setminus [0,1]$

Comment: Alas, I find your notation difficult to read. Are you saying that $1$ is in the boundary of $[0,1]\cap\Bbb Q$ within $\Bbb R$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I don't see why that is false.

Comment: @KennyLau on reading your edit it seems that you believe that Mr/Ms valer believes that $1$ is **not** a boundary point.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I'm very confused now. Obviously the answer is $\Bbb R \setminus (0,1)$.

Comment: $\operatorname{cl}(A^c) = \mathbb{R} \setminus (0,1)$ or it's not even closed (as it was stated first)

Comment: @KennyLau That might be obvious to you and me, but I thought perhaps Mr/Ms valer might find it profitable to ponder that question more.

Comment: Subtle nitpick.  What is your "universe" space?  Is it assumed to be $\mathbb R$.  Or is it assumed to be $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: @fleablood Seeing as Ms/Mr valer invokes $\Bbb R$ in her/his last line, I presume it's not $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Yes thanks for the answers R∖(0,1) is what i was looking for, the edit is ok,

Comment: I think the $cl(A^c)$ declaration is too abrubt with little justification. $A^c = ((-\infty, 0)\cap \mathbb I)\cup( (1,\infty) \cap \mathbb I)$ and $cl(A^c) = (\infty, 0] \cup [1,\infinty) = \mathbb R \setminus (0,1)$.  And we see that 0, 1$.  ... any 0, 1 are in the boundary and what you wrote excludes them.

Comment: I presume it is $\mathbb R$ and would bet the farm it is.  I'm merely pointing out that it is important to actually state ones topology.  Actually, I first misread the question and on second reading it is very obviously the space R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\operatorname{cl}(A^c) = \mathbb{R} \setminus (0,1)$ or it's not even closed (as it was stated first)

This set $\mathbb{R} \setminus (0,1)$ is thus also $\operatorname{bd}(A)$.